# How can I repair hdd using Disk Utility if First Aid options (Repair, Verify) are all greyed out?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, repair

Would really appreciate any help in fixing an external drive so can use with my Mac again.
I had a power loss & when computer rebooted it was unable to see the attached Freecom 320Gig Hdd (FAT32 formatted) in Finder, but could see it listed in Disk Utility. This had happened a few times before, but I was always able to either eject/remount it or repair and remount using Disk Utility, however this time when I click First Aid (for both entire drive or just the partition) all options like Repair and Verify are greyed out and cannot be clicked and I am basically stuck there. This was the case both for normal Disk Utility or using it from the restart-up/install option on rebooting, and was also the case when I tried to use the drive with a different Mac, so it seems to be a problem with the drive, not the particular mac. Strangely, the drive works fine with my wife’s PC, can even watch the videos on it, but it cannot mount or eject with any Macs. Any ideas on how to fix? The content on my drive is not that valuable, but I want to understand and fix the problem in case ever happens on a more valuable drive in the future. Thanks very much to anyone who can help!